# Usage of "be of"

Tags: prepositions, possessives

I've just read an article and saw this sentence:

> Hence, characterization of squat cracks is of particular interest for this research.

Why is there a *of*? If I restructured this like "... cracks is particular interest for this research" what would change?

There is another sentence like this:

> To study the nature of RCF defects and their behaviors, it is of great value to characterize the crack geometry.

Maybe *of* is used for possession but I can't understand the relation.

Comment: **cracks** is plural, BTW, so the verb needs to agree in number, **are** not **is**.

Comment: but the whole sentence is "characterization of cracks is ..." because of that I think "is" is correct.

Comment: @ Alperen koç: Unquestionably. The underlying grammatical *subject* of your text is (singular) ***characterization***, so the verb form must be ***is***, not ***are***.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to restate the sentence like this: "cracks is particular interest for this research" making "particular interest" a noun-phrase rather than a prepositional phrase complement of the verb.

Comment: "is of great value to characterize" is not quite grammatical. You'd want to use a phrase like **when characterizing** instead of the infinitive **to characterize**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I am a native speaker of English and I disagree strongly with your last comment.  And your first comment.  Both of the sentences that OP has quoted are perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Can anybody kindly tell me what the "squat cracks" is? Appreciate it!

Comment: @dan It is kind of fatigue which take place in railway rails and is like a corrugation. Its shape is  like that somebody sitting on the rail or squatting on the rail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construction **X is of Y** can be useful if you want to concisely *qualify* the **interest**, **value**, etc. with an *intensifier*.

Example:

> This book **is of great interest** to scholars in the field

which equals

> This book **is very interesting** to scholars in the field.

*“of **little** interest”* equates to *“is **not very** interesting”*. It does not equate to *“is not interesting”*, nor to *“is uninteresting”*: that would be expressed as *“is not of interest”*.

*“of **very little** interest*” roughly equates to *“is **very uninteresting** indeed”*, or *“is extremely uninteresting”*.

You can, however, go one further and say *“…of very little interest indeed*”, which means something like “*…is not interesting in the slightest*”.

It would be unusual to use ***small*** here: *…of small interest*. That feels correct but very literary. Conversely, you can say “…of big interest” in speech, but perhaps not in writing: it feels clumsy. You can say *…of huge | massive interest* (in speech), you would be unlikely to say *…of tiny interest* (*avoid*).

You may have noticed that it's probably easier to figure out these variants:

> *of interest*,
>   *of great interest*,
>   *of little interest*,
>   *of very great interest*,
>   *of very little interest*

and these negations

> *not of interest*,
>   *not of great interest*,
>   *of not great interest* (literary),
>   *of not very great interest* (literary),
>   *not of very great interest*

than it is to figure out these equivalents

> *interesting*,
>   *very interesting*,
>   *not very interesting*,
>   *extremely interesting*,
>   *extremely uninteresting*

and

> *uninteresting*,
>   *not very interesting*,
>   *not very interesting*,
>   *really not very interesting*
>   *not very interesting at all*

The pattern I have shown for **of interest** and its variants can be directly applied to

> *of value*, *of worth*, *of importance*, *of note* [notable, noteworthy], *of concern* [concerning].

However, to work out the adjectival forms of those attributes or characteristics is sometimes trickier and less regular: for example, there is no commonly used word *unvaluable* (avoid). Although it is in the dictionary I have never heard or seen it used: you would normally say

> *not of value* or *lacking in value*, *it lacks value*, *it has no value*.

(Note that *invaluable* means "so valuable that you cannot count its worth", "extremely valuable".)

So the good news is that you can always use a very regular pattern for **of Y** and its qualified variants and their negations.

The bad news is you may sound a bit like you're talking like a book, or like someone from the 1950s. But you will sound like you are well-educated :-).

My final comment would be: you can't use this construction with *any* noun that could be considered to be an attribute of the thing **X**. This goes to the earlier observation that **Y** must be an *abstract noun*

- *This book is of cost* (incorrect)
- *This book is costly* (correct)
- *This book is of great weight* (incorrect)
- *This book is very heavy* (correct)
- *This book weighs a lot* (correct)

Comment: I deleted the short paragraph about "worthy" (= honorable) because it is a side issue, and the answer was already quite long enough. However, if you find the edit to be too invasive, you can roll it back any time you want.

Answer (score 13):

Words like ***interest, value, importance*** are *abstract nouns* representing "attributes, qualities" that something might have.

The construction ***X is of Y*** (where ***Y*** is a noun as per above) asserts that ***X*** has the attribute associated with the specified noun. It wouldn't normally make logical or syntactic sense to assert that ***X*** actually ***is*** that attribute (as a noun).

So you must either convert the noun to an *adjective* *(**interesting, valuable, important**)* or precede the attribute noun by ***of*** to indicate that there is an "association" between the subject of the sentence and the attribute specified.

---

Almost as an aside I should mention that many learners get confused by how ***of*** and the "Saxon Genitive" (possessive apostrophe) work in English. I'm sure there will be a dedicated question about this somewhere on ELL, but for now I'll just make the point that such usages cover a broad span of senses including "association" as well as "ownership".

That same broad span of meanings can also be partly covered using the construction ***to have X*** (again, where ***X*** is an "abstract attribute" noun as above), so we can use any of these related/equivalent forms...

> *This answer is of value*
>   *This answer is valuable*
>   *This answer has value*
>    *This answer's value lies in its simplicity* <sup>1</sup>

Idiomatically, some of those forms work better that others in certain contexts, or with certain types of attribute, but *syntactically* and *semantically* they're all effectively equivalent and interchangeable.

---

<sup>1</sup> Kudos to @Keven for suggesting that excellent final "Saxon Genitive" example.

Comment: You could even go further and say "This answer's value lies in its simplicity" (or whatever verb phrase you want to complete the sentence with).

Comment: @Kevin: Excellent suggestion! Now I'm wondering if I should go the whole hog and include an "attributive noun" usage as well: [*The answer value is then multiplied by the question weight to determine the question result.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+answer+value+is+then%22)

Answer (score 3):

When  *{something} is **of interest** to {someone}*, {someone} finds {something} worthy of further attention or investigation.

of interest = worthy of (further) attention or investigation